# Imprimir dados diferentes de um array, de acordo com o valor do elemento

Tags: javascript, array

> Temos uma lista com nomes de todos os integrantes da família mas
> esqueceram de colocar o sobrenome!.
>
> Seu desafio será imprimir nome junto com o sobrenome "Macedo" para
> cada integrante da família. Mas temos uma exceção, temos um integrante
> com sobrenome diferente, se tiver algum "Pedro", coloque o sobrenome
> "Sousa".
>
> Dica: Utilize `for` e `continue` para criar a solução. Acrescente um
> espaço antes do sobrenome, por exemplo: " Sousa".

Código que eu fiz:

```js
var familia = ["Joana", "Felipe", "Gabriela", "Carlos", "Pedro", "Bruno"] 
var familia2 = " " 
for (i = 0; i < familia.length; i++){ 
    if( familia[i] == 'Pedro' ){ 
        console.log(familia[i] + ' Sousa') 
        continue 
    } 
    else if(familia[i] == 'Pedro'){ 
        console.log(familia[i] + ' Macedo')  
    }  
 }
```

Comment: var familia = ["Joana", "Felipe", "Gabriela", "Carlos", "Pedro", "Bruno"]
var  familia2 = " "
for (i = 0; i < familia.length; i++){
    if( familia[i] == 'Pedro' ){  
        console.log(familia[i] + ' Sousa')
        continue
    } else if(familia[i] == 'Pedro'){
        
    }console.log(familia[i] + ' Macedo')
    
} 

    
exempl de um dos codigos. Esse n tem muita logica! porem fiz alguns mais corretos, mesmo assim o terminal n aceitou

Comment: Coloquei o código que escreveu em comentário na pergunta, como você deve sempre fazer. Aproveito para perguntar também se ele ficou correto, ou seja se ficou como você tem no seu editor. Outra situação que é não muito clara para mim é o que quer dizer com "o terminal n aceitou"?

Answer (score 3):

O problema está no seu `if`:

```
if( familia[i] == 'Pedro' ){ 
    console.log(familia[i] + ' Sousa') 
    continue 
}  else if(familia[i] == 'Pedro'){ 
    console.log(familia[i] + ' Macedo')  
}
```

Primeiro você testa se o nome é "Pedro". Depois no `else` você testa se é "Pedro" de novo. Não faz sentido testar a mesma coisa duas vezes.

Além disso, o [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) dentro do `if` é desnecessário. Usando apenas o `if` e `else` você já garante que somente um dos caminhos é executado.

Segundo a regra do exercício, o que você deve fazer é: se o nome for "Pedro", sobrenome é "Sousa". Senão (para qualquer outro nome que não seja "Pedro") o sobrenome é "Macedo". Então ficaria assim:

```js
var familia = ["Joana", "Felipe", "Gabriela", "Carlos", "Pedro", "Bruno"];
for (var i = 0; i < familia.length; i++) {
    if (familia[i] == 'Pedro') { // se o nome é Pedro, o sobrenome é Souza
        console.log(familia[i] + ' Sousa');
    } else { // senão (se o nome não é Pedro), o sobrenome é Macedo
        console.log(familia[i] + ' Macedo');
    }
}
```

Também removi a variável `familia2` que não estava sendo usada para nada. E coloquei ponto e vírgula no final das linhas - sei que é opcional (o JavaScript não reclama se não tiver) e pode parecer "frescura", mas isso evita algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você não usá-los, como [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596) e [essa](/q/432960/112052) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](/q/3341/112052)).

---

Outra forma de fazer é usar um [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) para percorrer o array, e [*template strings*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) para imprimir:

```js
var familia = ["Joana", "Felipe", "Gabriela", "Carlos", "Pedro", "Bruno"];
for (var nome of familia) {
    if (nome == 'Pedro') {
        console.log(`${nome} Sousa`);
    } else {
        console.log(`${nome} Macedo`);
    }
}
```

Ou ainda o `forEach`, como sugerido na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/460908/112052).

---

## Sobre o uso de `continue`

O exercício dá a "dica" de usar [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue), mas eu acho completamente desnecessário. A ideia do `continue` é ir para a próxima iteração do `for`, ignorando qualquer coisa que venha depois.

Então ficaria assim:

```js
var familia = ["Joana", "Felipe", "Gabriela", "Carlos", "Pedro", "Bruno"];
for (var i = 0; i < familia.length; i++) {
    if (familia[i] == 'Pedro') { // se o nome é Pedro, o sobrenome é Souza
        console.log(familia[i] + ' Sousa');
        continue;
    }

    console.log(familia[i] + ' Macedo');
}
```

Ou seja, se entrar no `if`, ele imprime "Pedro Souza" e o `continue` faz com que ele vá para a próxima iteração do `for` (no caso, irá para o nome "Bruno"). Se o nome não for "Pedro", não entra no `if` e imprime o sobrenome "Macedo".

Mas eu acho uma complicação desnecessária, somente para forçar o uso do `continue`. Ainda acho a solução com `if`/`else` mais simples e clara.

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso aqui amigo

```
const familia = ["Joana", "Felipe", "Gabriela", "Carlos", "Pedro", "Bruno"]

familia.forEach(nome => {
  console.log(`${nome} ${nome === 'Pedro' ? 'Sousa' : 'Macedo'}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Como no exercício pedia o uso do `continue`, fiz assim

```js
var familia = ["Joana", "Felipe", "Gabriela", "Carlos", "Pedro", "Bruno"]

for (var i = 0; i < familia.length; i++){
    if(familia [i] == "Pedro") {
        console.log(familia[i] + " Sousa")
        continue
    }
    console.log( familia[i] + " Macedo")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < familia.length; i++){
    if (familia[i] == "Pedro")
    console.log(familia[i] + " Sousa")
    
    if(familia[i] !== "Pedro")
    console.log(familia[i] + " Macedo")
    continue
 }
```

Olá , consegui a solução do código assim:

No terminal do exercício não permitia o uso do else, ou else if... e exigia o uso do continue. foi a única forma que consegui fazer rodar. Espero que contribua.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

const familia = ["Joana", "Felipe", "Gabriela", "Carlos", "Pedro", "Bruno"]

familia.forEach(nome => {
console.log(`${nome} ${nome === 'Pedro' ? 'Sousa' : 'Macedo'}`)
})